# Disabling a scenario in a visual studio load test

Tags: visual-studio-2013, load-testing

All -- I am using Visual studio 2013 ultimate edition to run my load tests. I have more than one scenario configured on my load test. Each of the scenario run a different set of unit tests. Is is there a way to selectively run the scenarios ? In other words if there are more than one scenario configured, can I just run one of them and not run the rest ?

If the answer is 'NO', any ideas/suggestions would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways I have found:

One way is to set the user load to a constant zero in the unwanted scenarios.

Another way is to set the "Delay start time" of the unwanted scenarios to longer that the total test duration. This option only makes sense when "User test iterations" is false.